# How to get values coming from an external file with a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am getting values from locaStorage through this file:

```
const cartDataFn = () => {

    let cartData = []
    const cartDataStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartList'))
    
    if (cartDataStorage !== null) {
        cartData = cartDataStorage
    } 
    
    return cartData
} 


export default cartDataFn
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

As you see it is a function which returns an array (`cartData`)

If I import it into a function component I am able to get the array. Like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

import cartData from '../../../Data/cartData';


const Products = props => {
    
    let [cartState, setCart] = React.useState(cartData)

    console.log(cartState) // => It prints the array cartData
}

export default Products
```

However, when I try to do the same with a class component I don't know how to get `cartData`. If I log the file into console I get a visual represention of the function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import cartData from '../../Data/cartData'


class Layout extends Component {
    
    state = {
        cartState: cartData,
    }


    
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.state.cartState) // => It wont give me 'cartData', rather I'll get a visual draw of the whole function
    }    


    render () {

        return (

            <div>
                <p>Anything</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

How can I access these values in class components?

Comment: does `cartData()` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `cartDataFn` is a function, you need to *invoke* it in the class component:

```
class Layout extends Component {
    
    state = {
        cartState: cartData(),
    }
```

(preferably, give it a more accurate name to indicate that it's a function, not data)

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know why is it possible to get the values from a functional component without invoking the function?

Comment: The difference between the initialisations here is that in your example you are ending up using the lazy initialisation for the `useState` hook.   So react will execute the function for you to get the initial state. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: @Markus Maga I get it. Thank you very much.